# What is the point of destroying stalactites and stalagmites in The Witcher 3: Wild Hunt?

Tags: the-witcher-3

I started playing The Witcher: Wild Hunt on my PS4 a while ago, and updated it to last version. While I was playing I noticed that when I use witcher sense, the stalactites and stalagmites in caves glow yellow. I destroyed them with Aard and they blew up and turned into pieces. Why? Nothing was behind them nor was there something to loot. I tried this in other caves and I still didn't find anything. What is the point of them being able to be blown up by Aard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having done a complete playthrough including the two DLCs and every single quest (tracked with a checklist) + fully exploring the world including the most mundane of ruins and locked huts (tracked with a map site), I can safely say that there's not much of a reason to destroy them whenever you see them, other than if you see them blocking the very occasional chest. They don't drop anything or grant rewards per se.

My guess is that when they implemented Aard-ing boulders/walls/crates/barrels/doors to get passage, they decided they may as well do it for those rock formations as well, but in the end they didn't really incorporate the feature into the game's design.

Comment: My guess would be it's the other way around: they implemented stalactites and stalagmites that were destructible in order to make finding treasure more worthwhile, and these entities were also used as in-game clutter without deeming it necessary to remove the 'is_destructible flag', so to speak.